# Utilize pre-installed MinGW in GitHub actions?

Tags: c++, github-actions, mingw

Currently I've been using `egor-tensin/setup-mingw` to setup MinGW for our CI and it's been working fine.

```
- name: Set up MinGW
  uses: egor-tensin/setup-mingw@v2
- name: Configure
  run: cmake -S. -B build ... -G "Ninja"
```

However, I noticed that the windows runner already has MinGW pre-installed:

```
# https://github.com/actions/runner-images/blob/main/images/win/Windows2022-Readme.md
Mingw-w64 11.2.0
```

Currently the aforementioned action takes about 5 minutes to setup MinGW. Ideally using the pre-installed MinGW would speed up this part of the CI process.

How can I use the pre-installed MinGW to speed up our GitHub workflow?

Comment: Do you do something special to use it when you install it by that action?

Comment: `gcc` and `g++` are available in the `PATH` and you can directly use them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's very simple, just use `bash` as the shell. This is how I do it:

```yaml
  mingw64-gcc:
    name: MinGW GCC

    runs-on: windows-2019

    defaults:
      run:
        shell: bash

    steps:
      - name: "Setup"
        run: |
          gcc --version
```

Comment: It's not specific to the `bash` shell on the Windows runner.

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't able to get anything with `shell:` to work.  Instead, a simple solution is to just add

```
$env:PATH = "C:\msys64\usr\bin;$env:PATH"
```

at the start of the `run:` block.  This will put the msys64 environment on your PATH.

For other environments, you will need to put first the environment-specific bin dir, then the msys64 bin dir to match how MSYS2 sets it up.  So, for the ucrt64 environment, it would look like

```
$env:PATH = "C:\msys64\ucrt64\bin;C:\msys64\usr\bin;$env:PATH"
```

This obviously has limitations in that you don't have an actual bash shell, but it was enough for me to successfully compile a CMake project.